# How to orderBy with Angular.js using the result of a split string function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I am displaying a table of sample employee data, and I need to orderBy lastname. The data is provided via a .JSON file, and the names are in a single string:

```
users.json

{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Bob Smith",
  "username": "Eloyn.Skilles",
  "email": "smith.bob@bolly.biz",
  "address": {
    "street": "Rox Trial",
    "suite": "Suite 2890",
    "city": "Smashmouth",
    "zipcode": "58604­1099",
    "geo": {
      "lat": "27.8718",
      "lng": "21.8984"
    }
  },
  "phone": "210.067.6132",
  "website": "elvis.io",
  "company": {
    "name": "Johns Group",
    "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task­force",
    "bs": "generate enterprise e­tailers"
  }
}
```

So far, I have been able to split the string into two:

```
MainController.js

/* Function to split strings where there is a space present */
$scope.nameSplitter = function(string, index) {
    $scope.array = string.split(' ');
    return $scope.result = $scope.array[index];
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>

    <!-- Would like to ideally orderBy last name -->
    <tr ng-repeat="user in userData | orderBy:'name'">
        <td>{{ nameSplitter(user.name,1) }}, {{ nameSplitter(user.name,0) }}</td> <!--0 returns first name, 1 returns last name-->
        <td><a ng-href="mailto:{{user.email}}" target="_blank">{{user.email}}</a></td>
        <td><a ng-if="user.phone !== ''" href="tel:{{nameSplitter(user.phone, 0)}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{nameSplitter(user.phone, 0)}}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a></td>
</table>
```

I tried this `orderBy:'nameSplitter(user.name, 1)'` with various bracket combinations, but no luck.

Comment: How do you plan to handle the "edge cases", e.g. single given name only (Pele), title plus single given name (Pope Francis), multiple parts to a family name (Ludwig van Beethoven), multiple family names (Enrique Peña Nieto), multiple given names (Sarah Jessica Parker), etc.? If you can, you should consider restructuring your table to include preferred family name, preferred given name, preferred form of address... depending on how you plan to use the data.

Comment: This is a very good point. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. The data in this project I am working on is simple and fortunately doesn't (and won't) contain the edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

orderBy accepts functions as well.

```
ng-repeat="user in userData | orderBy:getlastname" 

 $scope.getlastname = function(user) {
    var name =  user.name.split(' ');
    return name[1];
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! The problem is I didn't know how to get orderBy to accept a function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Array`, `function` or an `attribute name` in `orderBy` [Angular orderBy docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

So in html

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in userData | orderBy:myCustomOrderBy">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.myCustomOrderBy = function(user){
    return user.name.split(' '); //what you intent to here play on your own
}
```

The current user in scope is passed as an argument

Answer (score 0):

orderBy with a string is an expression, so you can include functions, alternatively a custom function can be provided as an argument instead of the string.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in userData | orderBy:'name.split(\' \')[1]'">
```

Comment: you'll have to escape those single quotes